# Why can`t add margin-left to my div?

Tags: html, css

I have this site: 
http://dl.dg-site.com/functionmentes/

This is code CSS:

```
@media screen and (width:1024px)
{
    #titlu_footer
    {
        margin-left:90px;
    }
}
```

I tried to add this code but not working.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your media query change `width` to `min-width` or `max-width`

## Additional problem

This is currently your CSS for #titlu_footer

```
.page-id-1637 #titlu_footer {
  color: #264572;
  font-family: muli, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 302px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

If you look using chrome/firefox developer tools you'll see that `margin-left 302px` is taking precedence over your media queries.

Comment: @gigiion: Why don't you start by removing the `@media` statments to see if that works as expected. If it does, then @AR7 is obviously onto the issue here. But you need to make some effort to resolve this. We can't see your changes to verify they are correct, we don't know what resolution your devices it. Narrow it down.

Comment: I looked through the CSS of the site and the problem is that he has margin-left defined outside of his media queries so that the value in his media query is being overridden.